# Process Builder: Is "evaluate a record multiple times" inherited to sub-processes?

Tags: process-builder, recursion

When creating a Lightning Process, you can choose the flag "Allow process to evaluate a record multiple times in a single transaction". If a process A invokes a sub-process B, does the setting on process A affect process B?

When this recursion flag is active on process A but not on process B, or the other way around, how does process B behave?

(All process work on the same object.)

Comment: this is amenable to testing by examining the debug log. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a sub-process, it will get triggered when the main process calls it. So, if your main process gets evaluated again, and the criteria to trigger the sub-process is still true, the sub process will fire.